# easiest way to see if array has array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

the only way I can think to do this is to do something like:

```
for current array length,
  for array to check length
   if current array i === array to check i
      true
```

Essentially I have the following:

```
arr = [[1,2], [0,3]];
```

When I want to add another array to this arrays: [1,2] I need to first see if it exists, if it does do not push it on to the array, if it doesn't then push it.

**Is there some really simple, clean readable way to check if an array exists in an array of arrays before pushing it on to the list of elements?**

### Update:

it should be pretty simple, you have array:

```
arr = [[1,2], [0,3]];
```

You try and push:

```
[1,2]
```

Nothing happens.

You try and push: `[4,6]`. New array: `[[1,2], [0,3], [4,6]];`

Comment: I don't actually know how to implement this, so pseudo code is all I got ...

Comment: So at least show a couple of inputs, and matching outputs, that demonstrate your desired behavior.

Comment: You're not far off. You'd want to loop over the first array and then compare the inner arrays against your check. But you can't use a simple comparison operator for that. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/1457603) for how to compare arrays.

Comment: I thought there would be some simple lodash way or some underscore way of doing this ... ??

Comment: Is that always the level of your complexity? a few numerical values inside the sub arrays?

Comment: yup thats as complicated as it gets

Comment: When you say your array contains `[1,2]` and then pushing `[1,2]` does nothing, are they the same object reference? Or you want to do nothing when pushing an array which contains the same items as an already pushed one?

Comment: I would use Array's [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check for presence.

Comment: Pushing `[2,1]` would add it to the array right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using underscore you can do this:

Initial approach:

```
    var i = _.findIndex(arr, function (e) {
         return (e.join(',') === arr_elem.join(','));
    });

    if (i === -1) {
        arr.push(arr_elem);
    }
```

**EDIT** Considering performance (Also read the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4025924/1023432)), it would be better to check array equality using a brute loop approach:

```
function arraysEqual(arr1, arr2) {
    if(arr1.length !== arr2.length)
        return false;
    for(var i = arr1.length; i--;) {
        if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

var i = _.findIndex(arr, function (e) {
     return arraysEqual(arr_elem, e);
});

if (i === -1) {
    arr.push(arr_elem);
}
```

Comment: Comparing arrays by converting them into strings first?

Comment: @Pluto Thanks, I gave that first solution as it was easier to write, just made some edits after a little more research!

Answer (score 3):

Since the complexity is limited, a simple solution exists:

```js
function maybePush(to, val) {
  if(!to.some(function(curr) {
      return curr.length !== val.length ||
        curr.some(function(v, i) { return val[i] === v; });
    })) {
     to.push(val);
  }
}


arr = [[1,2], [0,3]];
maybePush(arr, [1,2]);
maybePush(arr, [5,6]);
console.log(arr);
```

You'd probably want to add some guards, check that what you expect to be an array really is an array and so on (left out for clarity)...

The idea is simple, check if any of the values of the outer array is equal to the `val` array, using an iterative comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your array `arr` contains only integers and arrays, a simple check to see if the array matches the flattened array will indicate if the array contains inner arrays.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,[4,5],6];

if (JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify([].concat.apply([], arr))) {
  // Does not contain an array
}
```

The snippet `[].concat.apply([], arr)` flattens the array `arr`.

Comment: `[].concat` creates a new, different array. `===` will always return false.

Comment: You are correct @Oriol, I forgot to stringify the arrays.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP wants, and the approach doesn't work since it unconditionally concatenates the new array to the end of the existing array, creating a new, different array with more members therefore it will always evaluate to false.